# Elasticsearch MasterNotDiscoveredException Java Node Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect with a Java application from localhost to my elasticsearch cluster on a root server. My problem is that the java client is not able to get a connection.

Ports 9200-9299 and 9300-9400 are opened on the root server(groupelite.de).

I configured my elasticsearch cluster to use unicast discovery and set its inet ip address as "network.host". 
This is how I instantiate my client:

```
NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
  .clusterName("neeedo-es")
  .settings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .classLoader(classOf[Settings].getClassLoader)
    .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", "groupelite.de:9300")
    .put("node.name", "neeedo-client"))
  .client(true)
  .data(false)
  .node()
```

And this is my elasticsearch.yml https://gist.github.com/MeiSign/ccfdcc62643c1185bab3

The firewall on the server should be turned off. You can also reach es with http http://www.groupelite.de:9200/

The server is running ubuntu 14.04. Elasticsearch version is 1.4.2 on client and server.

Iam not very used to networking stuff but I hope to get some ideas from you guys what is wrong.

Edit 1:
The server log is showing a ConnectionClosed Exception from time to time. But it does not appear when the client tries to connect, you cant see the client in the logs at all.

```
[2015-01-31 18:31:45,921][WARN ][transport.netty] [neeedo-s1] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x1685f631]], closing connection
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Edit 2:
I have found out that it works when I use a transport client in my application. Does this give any hint what is wrong?

Comment: Try with the ip address of the server. Also, when connecting with the client, do you get any logs? Can you provide those?

Comment: I ve tried it with the ip adress already and it is not working aswell. When the client tries to connect I see nothing in the Logs but there is a Connection Closed Exception from time to time. I have added the logs to my question